# HTML5 video only play if play button is clicked, not surrounding area

Tags: javascript, html, video

When clicking on a video, a details view should open within a popup. This happens with no issue via my drawEditForm() function, but it also begins playing the video (even if the play button wasn't clicked but an area of the video was). **Is there a way that I can dictate that the video should only play if the play button is clicked and not the surrounding area of the video?**

```
        <div class="thumbDiv" onclick="asset.drawEditForm('2081833185')">
            <video controls="controls" preload="metadata">
                <source src="assets/myvideo.mp4#t=0.1" type="video/mp4">
            </video>        
        </div>
```

Comment: maybe removing `eventListener` from `video`?

Comment: What behavior do you expect once the video is playing? Click the video and just pause the video and run `drawEditForm()`? Or never use `drawEditForm()` until the video has ended either by user stopping it (not pausing but really stopping it) or when the video has played the whole duration of video?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `preventDefault()`:

```
document.querySelector('.video').addEventListener('click', function () {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```